# Postman request body in Pre-request script

Tags: postman

I have a Postman Pre-request script to add a HMAC key to a request. This works great unless the body has an environment variable in it. So if I have the following body

```
{
    "key": "{{key}}",
    "value": "some value"
}
```

When with the key value set to be ***sample*** when the request is sent, the body contains the following

```
{
    "key": "sample",
    "value": "some value"
}
```

This is what I would expect to happen. However when accessing the request body in the Pre-Request Script,

```
console.log(pm.request.body.toString());
```

I get the following

```
{
    "key": "{{key}}",
    "value": "some value"
}
```

How can I get the body with the variables having been replaced, so that it is what would be sent to the server?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can interpolate the placeholders using following function:

```
function interpolate (value) {
    const {Property} = require('postman-collection');
    return Property.replaceSubstitutions(value, pm.variables.toObject());
}
```

In your case:

```
console.log(interpolate(pm.request.body.toString()));
```

Comment: Simple and easy and works perfectly with Postman v7.12.0. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone finds this you can use this instead now.

```
var requestBody = pm.variables.replaceIn(pm.request.body);
```